# XML Parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

```
<exam>

<question type="multichoice">
   <name>
       <text>Demo Imported Question</text>
   </name>
   <questiontext format="html">
       <text>What is SEO?</text>
   </questiontext>
   <answer fraction="0">
  <text>Son of English Organization</text>
 <feedback><text>WRONG</text></feedback>


</answer>
   <answer fraction="100">
      <text>Search Engine Optimization</text>
      <feedback><text>Right on!</text></feedback>
   </answer>
   <answer fraction="0">
      <text>Silver of England Office</text>
      <feedback><text>Ooops!</text></feedback>
   </answer>
   <questiontext format="html">
       <text>How many stars are there on US flag ?</text>
   </questiontext>
   <answer fraction="0">
      <text>46</text>
     <feedback><text>WRONG</text></feedback>
   </answer>
   <answer fraction="100">
      <text>52</text>
      <feedback><text>Right on!</text></feedback>
   </answer>
   <answer fraction="0">
      <text>54</text>
      <feedback><text>Ooops!</text></feedback>
   </answer>

   </question>
</exam>
```

The above is a dummy test xml and I like to read in by Java code snippet and simply ouput as

```
Question : what is seo?
answer: Son of English Organizatio
answer: Search Engine Optimization
answer: Silvet of england Office
```

...likewise for the next question

Does anyone has a best way to do this ?  Thanks so much

Comment: Why do you have two questions within a single question element? Did you design the schema?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a "standard" way to do it, I'd recommend using [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) since it's part of Java SE 6.

First, create an xsd schema for your xml files. Then use the command line `xjc` tool found in Java SDK. This will generate Java JAXB classes according to your schema.

Afterwards, read on how to use JAXB to painlessly obtain elements you need from your XML file. A nice and simple tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html).

Comment: JAXB is the way to go, a fair comparison with XStream can be found here, http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html. +1

Comment: jaxb may not be suited because of the lack of schema

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: have you read the first sentence of the second paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

use `DOM parser` . Here is the link that best fits you [How to read XML file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries like dom4j, jdom, xtream etc available for reading and manipulating xml data. I found dom4j very easy.

Answer (score 0):

[VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sf.net) is the XML API that combines a number of benefits (perforamnce, memory usage and ease of use).

Comment: Don't you think that this brief answer looks too much like auto promotion?